# How do I prevent Mouse4 click from navigating backwards?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to prevent the execution of any action that might come from clicking any of the 5 mouse buttons. This is what I've tried:

```js
$(document).on('click contextmenu', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
```

This works for `left` and `middle` click, but not for `right`, `mouse4` or `mouse5` click.
Clicking `mouse4` or `mouse5` causes the browser to navigate backwards or forwards, and `right` click causes a context menu to appear.

I'm running the code inside a Chromium-based browser.

Comment: My mouse has only 3 buttons, how does it make sence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. The mouse click is handled by the browser *before* it ever reaches the JS execution environment of the page you are on. Frankly, I think it would be pretty awful if web pages had that much power again. I'm saying again because anyone who remembers how browsers used to be before pop-up blocking and before pages were prevented from changing window dimensions can tell you how terrible it was back then.